# How to get Talkback's rectangle foucse on DrawerLayer?

Tags: android, focus, talkback

In my application I use DrawerLayout to show same help information. So I put it over actuall activity. Now I want to add TalckBack function and I cannot make that the any of view in DrawerLayout get the yellow rectangle (which marks focus in talkback mode). 
The Drawerlayout view is loaded on demand by inflantign it.

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.drawer);
drawerHelp = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.help, drawerLayout, false);
```

What I try:

in xml add:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
```

In code:

```
requestChildFocus()
requestFocus()
requestChildFocusFromTouch()
```

but still no luck.
So how to force the rectangle mark in talkback mode for ImageButton?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - prevent TalkBack from announcing TextView title aloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723797/android-prevent-talkback-from-announcing-textview-title-aloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by adding

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

to all element in drawer layout and to other not nedeed elements in help layout.